# Wikipedia article Tensors may contain an error.

Tags: linear-transformations

I have a question regarding the article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor.
A quote from that article follows:

> "The components of a vector can respond in two distinct ways to a change of basis where the new basis vectors $\hat e _i$ are expressed in terms of the old basis vectors $e_j$ as,
>
> $$\hat e _i = \sum \limits _{j=1} ^n R_i^j  e_j .$$
>
> Here $R_i^j$ are the entries of the change of basis matrix."

If $e_j$ is a basis vector, as stated in the quoted sentence, then it is necessary to accept that $e_j$ is the $j$-th vector in the basis vectors.  The product shown between the change of basis matrix $R$ with each basis vector $e_j$ appears then to be wrong.  Unless the author is referring to each component in two basis vectors, where the $\hat e$ vector produced is indexed by $i$ while the $e$ vector is indexed by $j$.

However that appears to be strange (besides being pointless since my understanding is that if you have the change of basis matrix $R$ then you already know what the new basis vectors are, simply the column vectors in $R$).  If $R$ is indexed as shown then each product is of a column vector component in $R$'s $i$ column indexed by $j$, with a $j$ component in the basis vector $e$.  If $n=2$ then $R$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix and $\hat e _1 = r_{11} e_1 + r_{21}  e_2$.  That is inconsistent with how I learned to form the product of a matrix with a vector, so I consider it strange.

Can someone kindly disambiguate this for me?  I appreciate your time to consider it.

Comment: The notation clearly indicates that the index of summation is $j$ and $\widehat e$ is indexed by $i$.

Comment: The author is using the [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), which is fairly common when working with tensors in mathematical physics.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I am mostly clear on the indexing and notation.  I looked at e_j as a list of vectors and my first comment was that it appears to be incorrect with respect to the index on R.  According to the indexing shown, the entire set of e vectors are indexed through by j for EACH e-hat_i vector produced.  That is inconsistent with what I've understood about a change of basis from one vector space to another.

Comment: If I accept these are vectors being indexed then the consequence seems to require that a vector e-hat_i is produced by the sum of all products of R(j,i) components (matrix column indexed by j) with every corresponding vector e_j.  To be honest, I don't see how to construct that sum of products.  I'm not saying it can't be done.  Maybe you can explain how that is accomplished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two things. First, when you have a matrix $R = (R _i ^j)$  ($i = 1, \dots, m$ indicates the row, $j = 1, \dots, n$ indicates the column) and a vector $v = (v_j) _{j = 1, \dots, n}$ (having $n$ rows and $1$ column), you can form their product $Rv$ which is a vector with $m$ lines and $1$ row; the $i$-th component of this vector is $\sum \limits _{j=1} ^n R _i ^j v_j$.

Second, when you have a matrix as above and $n$ vectors $e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n$, you may create $m$ new vectors $\hat e _1, \hat e _2, \cdots, \hat e _m$ according to the formula $\hat e _i = \sum \limits _{j=1} ^n R _i ^j e_j$.

Note that in the first paragraph you multiply the entries of $R$ with some *numbers* (the components of $v$), while in the second paragraph you multiply them with *vectors*. (Note also that in the paragraph quoted from Wikipedia $m=n$.) The two formulae look identical, but the natures of the objects involved therein are different (numbers versus vectors).

Comment: Alex, thanks for your time to respond.  My understanding it that the lower index on R "i" indicates the column "index" so as you iterate i down the column you are picking matrix components from a ROW.  In the summation shown "i' is the free index and "j" is iterated for each product in the sum, j=1, n.

Comment: I agree that you can produce new vectors using this matrix multiplication but I find it strange in that is is not consistent with my previous experience with change of basis matrices.  It may be technically correct but it does not appear to be functionally correct in the context of change of basis.  Besides, as you probably know, a change of basis matrix is formed by taking the new basis vectors as columns in the matrix.  So how can I see R as a change of basis if e-hat vectors are "new basis" vectors.  In this Tensor topic it is strange to me but I admit to having a limited exposure to this.

Comment: @JohnHunsberger: Alas, I don't think that I can help you any further: this matter is so clear to me, that I cannot understand what you don't understand.

Comment: LOL, I am pretty dense.

Comment: Shouldn't “$n$ lines and $1$ row” be “$n$ rows and one column”?

Comment: @egreg: Corrected. I've never understood why English speakers say "row" instead of "line", and this confuses me even after so many years.

Comment: @JohnHunsberger: There's no need to accept an answer just to be polite. If an answer does not entirely satisfy you, just wait for a potentially clearer one, nobody will feel offended.

Comment: Good advice.  Thanks.